# What does "null!" default value of property mean?

Tags: c#, syntax, properties, operators

I have seen this below code in somewhere. There is a TodoItems property in the TodoContext class and it has a default value of "null!". I know this is a default value set for intended property but what does the exclamation mark(**!**) do at the end of the "null" value?

```
public class TodoContext : DbContext
{
    public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null!` basically means `null` but the `!` symbol suppresses the warning since your intentions are that it will be changed in a constructor or other places.